# using click event with registerHelper (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, registerhelper

Im trying to use registerHelper to respond to a click event on my page.
i seem to be having difficulty getting the page to perform a function based on a click event.

The function below runs when the page renders.

```
 Template.registerHelper('deletetask',  function () {
         Tasksdb.remove(this._id);
```

how do i get it to run on a click event? I have tried something like:

```
Template.registerHelper('deletetask', 'click.delete' : function () {
     Tasksdb.remove(this._id);
```

it just errors out.I think my syntax is off or i have to do it some other way.

Thanks

Comment: don't assume the api running your way. Read the documentation first http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template *helpers* return values for display. Template [events](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events) are designed for, you guessed it, handling events.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .delete': function(ev){
    Tasksdb.remove(this._id);
  }
});
```

Note that `this` will be the data context corresponding to the *instance* of `myTemplate` that was clicked on.